# How to paint over just one image in android?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-animation

The purpose is to have an empty bucket of water and fill it based on a (changing) system parameter. `minimumValue = 0, maximuValue = SYSTEM_PARAMETER`

I do have the bucket image (`*.png` with transparencies) and I know I should use `canvas/drawables` yet how can I paint the water (blue) just inside the bucket?

I could change the entire background but then it would fill the bucket inside and outside.

Comment: use two pngs: an empty bucked and full filled one, before drawing the second one set clip area canvas.clipRect() to show current level of water

Comment: I have a solution.. please wait .. testing and giving you a working copy of that.. :)

Comment: Please check my answer. You find it helpful. Please accept and upvote if it helped you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is the solution.

### Step 1

Copy/Paste following Custom class.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ImageView;

public class DrawView extends ImageView {

    Paint mPaint;
    int percent = 0;
    int toFillHeight;
    private RectF box;

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        box = new RectF(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public int calculateFillArea() {
        return percent * 200 / getHeight();
    }

    public void setPercentage(int percent) {
        this.percent = percent;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        //you can remove these two lines if you don't want background color
        mPaint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()), mPaint);

        toFillHeight = calculateFillArea();

        // Arc
        mPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#33b5e5"));
        box.set(0, getHeight() - toFillHeight, getWidth(), getHeight());
        canvas.drawRect(box, mPaint);

    }
}
```

### Step 2

Use that custom class in layout like below.

```
<com.example.rounded.DrawView
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

### Step 3

Following is the way i have used it.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    DrawView view;
    int percentage = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        view = (DrawView) findViewById(R.id.view1);

        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (percentage < 99) {
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            view.setPercentage(percentage);
                            percentage++;
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }
}
```

**Note**

This is rough example. You need to change `DrawView` as per your requirement. I have just filled that rectangle with blue color.

You can fill rectangle with percentage using `setPercentage(int)` method of `DrawView`.

Comment: It gives a null pointer exeption on                           view.setPercentage(percentage).

Comment: Not possible. Have you changed anything in code? Its a tested code. I have written it and checked in device. Running very smoothly.

Comment: Nop, just copy/paste. If I comment the view.setPercentage(percentage) line it works.

Comment: can you show me logs at what line of code or which error it is providing. So that i can fix that..

Comment: Sure, but only later on -no code here. Yet I do have a question, will it work over an image (the so called bucket) without painting it outside? Will I have to define the bounds of the "bucket"

Comment: @miguels if that bucket is not square/rectangle with the shape by which you can fill it, i think you need to create a bound. It sill not fluid colors outside it. I only know concept of it. Never implemented.